# Indicate that a column should be indexed with TypeORM's entity schema files

Tags: orm, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I'm using TypeORM with [entity schema files](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/separating-entity-definition) and I need to indicate that an index needs to be created on a column. If I were using decorators, I could simply do:

```js
@Entity()
class Foo {
    @Index()
    @Column({ type: String })
    toBeIndexed: string;
}
```

However there seems to be no way to do the same thing just with entity schema files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me share my example with you. hope this code snippet will give you a hint.

```js
import { EntitySchema, Column, Index } from 'typeorm';

export const UserSchema = new EntitySchema({
  name: 'User',
  columns: {
    id: {
      type: Number,
      primary: true,
      generated: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
    },
    age: {
      type: Number,
    },
  },
  indices: [
    {
      name: 'IDX_NAME',
      columns: ['name'],
    },
  ],
});
```